# Change lock screen to gdm in kubuntu (kde)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, gdm, display-manager

I have installed gdm3 on Kubuntu and changed the default display manager from sddm to gdm3, and the login screen works fine, it looks just like Ubuntu. but the lock screen (when you press ctrl+alt+L) still looks like the standard KDE lock screen. Is it possible to change the lock screen to gdm3?

Comment: I suspect my answer below is not what you want. In any case, if you like the look of Ubuntu, why not just use Ubuntu and install whichever "KDE" applications you need?

Answer (score -2):

On a **normal** Kubuntu system, open *System Settings > Desktop Behavior > Screen Locking > Appearance* and choose the image you want. You can even point to an appropriate image stored somewhere on your system or download an image from KDE Store:

[image: GUI for changing lock screen wallpaper]

Note: I'm using the default display manager and not gdm3. I don't know if there are any side-effects to changing display managers.

Comment: It's not the background image that I want to change, but the entire interface. I think that the gdm3 login/lock screen looks a lot cleaner than sddm. I there was a gdm3 theme for sddm I would use it but I could not find one.